# Running SSIS Package in SQL Server Agent is too long

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, deployment, ssis

I have package ssis, when I running in Visual Studio need 30 minutes to finished. But, when I run in SQL Server Agent need 8 hours to finished or can failed because too long running.
How I fixing this problem to I can run in SQL Server Agent with faster or just 30 minutes?
Thank you

Comment: Are you running VS on the same machine as SQL Server Agent?

Comment: What is different between the VS execution and the scheduled execution? Do you use the same source/destination? What is the SSIS package *doing*?